# Get value with second key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have list or array :

```
$var_menu_sub["1"]["1"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #1";
$var_menu_sub["1"]["2"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #2";
$var_menu_sub["1"]["3"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #3";
$var_menu_sub["2"]["this_key"] = "1|Change Password";
$var_menu_sub["3"]["1"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #1";
$var_menu_sub["3"]["2"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #2";
```

Then how to get value "Change Password" if i just use key "this_key" without known the "2" key in array variables ?

Like this (??? =  mean dynamic):

```
$var_menu_sub["???"]["this_key"] = "1|Change Password";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one `this_key`:

```
echo current(array_column($var_menu_sub, 'this_key'));
```

If there is more than one `this_key`, then you just need to `foreach` over the result:

```
foreach(array_column($var_menu_sub, 'this_key') as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: It works with **array_column()**, thanks, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

```
<?php
$var_menu_sub["1"]["1"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #1";
$var_menu_sub["1"]["2"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #2";
$var_menu_sub["1"]["3"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #3";
$var_menu_sub["2"]["this_key"] = "1|Change Password";
$var_menu_sub["3"]["1"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #1";
$var_menu_sub["3"]["2"] = "1|Sub Menu Label #2";

// Loop over entire array
foreach ($var_menu_sub as $data) {
    //Loop over the array which is indexed by the key you know
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // Look for that key
        if ($key == 'this_key') {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it works, but i need more simple line code, then i use **array_column()** :)